# Switch statements and ranges of numbers

Tags: actionscript-3

How do you craft a switch statement in as3 to make the case apply to an entire range of numbers?

```
if (mcPaddle.visible == true)
{
    switch (score)
    {
        case  10://10 to 100
            myColor.color = 0x111111;
            break;
        case 110://110 to 1000
            //etc etc
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple ways to make the case apply for all numbers between 10-100, and 110-1000, but can't seem to find a way to do it, and I can't find the proper syntax for such a thing in as3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a switch block :

```
var score:Number = 123;

switch(true){

    case score > 120 && score < 125 :
        trace('score > 120 && score < 125');
        break;

    case score > 100 && score < 140 :
        trace('score > 100 && score < 140');
        break;

    case score == 123 :
        trace('score == 123');
        break;

}
//score > 120 && score < 125
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and is exactly what I needed. Never thought to change the switch statement to check for true on everything, then check the score's truth value.

Comment: @alxx - It might look dirty, but much to my own surprise, this switch range code actually outperforms the if-else chains. I tested 1 million random numbers going into ten equal sized ranges and the switch consistently achieved 15% better performance!

Comment: @alxx now that is a good reason to use it. upvote for performance testing

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript's switch statement doesn't work with ranges, but you can easily do it with if/else chains:

```
if (score >= 10 && score <= 100)
{
    //10 - 100
}
else if (score <= 110)
{
    //101 - 110
}
else if (score <= 1000)
{
    //111 - 1000
}
```

Comment: Well damn, I was hoping to avoid just that scenario, because large else if nests are unsightly and messy, but if switch statements can't do ranges I suppose I have no choice.

Comment: They don't really have to be nested, you can chain them. If you don't put four spaces offset after each level, if/else blocks stay very readable.

Answer (score 0):

switch statements just restatements of `if (a = b) or (a = c) or (a = d) ...` type constructs. THey're not intended for ranges. You can somewhat simulate it using fallthroughs:

```
switch (score) {
   case 10:
   case 11:
   case 12:
   case 13:
   case etc...
        blah blah blah
        break;
}
```

but that's a ludicrously dumb way to go. Much easier/terser to use a regular `if()`

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for how to use this in HTML/jQuery, I've used @OXMO456's answer to create this simple pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jHFoB

You just have to set the `var` normally and remove the lines starting with `trace`.

Ps. I'm adding this as an answer since I don't have enough rep to comment on his. If anyone can, please move/copy this there. Thanks!