# Can percentage probability be done with a switch and ranges in C?

Tags: c, random, if-statement, switch-statement, range

I'm currently using a random number and a series of if statements to assign a pointer to one of four lists using the following:

```
struct listinfo//struct holds head, tail and the number of entries for the n2l, norm, known and old lists
{
    struct vocab * head;
    int entries;
    struct vocab * tail;
};
```

...

```
int list_selector=0;
struct listinfo * currentlist = NULL;
//select a list at random, using the percentage probabilities in the if statements.
//FISH! Can this be done with a switch and ranges?
list_selector = (rand() % 100)+1;
if (list_selector<33) currentlist = &n2l;
if (list_selector>32&&list_selector<95) currentlist=&norm;
if (list_selector>94&&list_selector<100) currentlist = &known;
if (list_selector==100) currentlist = &old;
```

I was just wondering if there's a neater way to do this using ranges in the switch as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839937/switch-statements-and-ranges-of-numbers) question.
If so, an example would be great. Any additional tips would be much appreciated too.

Edit: Fixed! Was linking to wrong page instead of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839937/switch-statements-and-ranges-of-numbers).

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand the terms and the problem you're having. Please include all relevant code, including what `n2l`, `norm`, `known` and `old` are for. Also, are you really picking a whole list, and not an element of a list? If so, do you have a data structure that holds `n2&l` & Co (a list of lists)?

Comment: @phihag: Sorry! My link was wrong. Following it should explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe C supports ranges in switch statements.  You could use an if-else construct to reduce comparisons:

```
if( x == 100 )
  ...
else if( x > 94 )
  ...
```

And your random number generator is not properly random: RAND_MAX is unlikely to be divisible by 100, so some numbers may be more common than others.  Here is the accepted way to convert rand() to a properly random distribution from 1 to 100:

```
x = 1 + (int) ( 100.0 * ( rand() / ( RAND_MAX + 1.0 ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted before, C doesn't support ranges as switch case selectors.   For a compact and efficient form, you could use C's ternary operator, eg:

```
r = (random() % 100)+1;
currentlist = r<33? &n2l : r<95? &norm : r<100? &known : &old;
```

or if you prefer could use nested if's, like:

```
currentlist = &n2l;
if (r>32) {
  currentlist = &norm;
  if (r>94) {
    currentlist = &known;
    if (r==100)
      currentlist = &old;
  }
}
```

Note, per man rand, "on older rand() implementations... the lower-order bits are much less random than the higher-order bits", so I prefer random() to rand().  Or go with the `100.0 * ( rand() / ( RAND_MAX + 1.0))` formula suggested by asc99c.

Answer (score 0):

No, in this situation, using the less than, greater than, is much more efficient.  For a switch, you'd have to outlay all of the different possibilities.

```
   case  1:     
         2:
         3:
         4:   
       /*write all the numbers out all the way up to 31, then for 32 */
        32: currentlist = &n2l;
   break;
   case  33:  
         34:
         35:
        /*write out all of these numbers until 94, then for 95 */
         95:  currentlist=&norm;
   break;         
   /*etc*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to change that `(rand() % 100)+1` to provide fewer possible values, you'll have a much easier time with the solution.

If that's not possible, I'm trying to come up with a solution, but it seems like a tricksy problem at first glance (without listing every possible value).

Comment: @yi_H: except the example has the rand right there. If the actual code looks like that, this is the wrong problem; in fact, it's one that need not exist. The distribution should be identical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Please try to understand the original code.

Comment: I understand perfectly, my question to the OP is whether they have control of the `rand() % 100` line, or if that can be modified to help simplify the solution. If it can be changed, there are far more possible solutions, and they tend to be much simpler.

Comment: no, you don't understand. the last condition has to be executed with 1% probability, so you cannot lower 100.

Comment: You assume that the final values have to be produced by an identical share of intermediate values. Something like `(x==100)?4:(x%3)` can account for that easily (not considering the other segments in this case). There are 4 possible lists, thus only 4 values are *required*.

Comment: @peachykeen: I'm trying to get a 1% chance of choosing an entry from the 'old' list, a 5% chance of one from the 'known' list, approx. 1 in 3 chance of one from the 'n2l' list, and the rest from the 'norm' list.

Comment: @M_M: right. My suggestion is to try and reduce the values down before you use a switch, assuming that's what you do. For example, bit tests would give `(x&1)` a 50% chance, then `(x&2)` gets 25%, etc. If you're able to change the code that generates the values, you may be able to produce values that are easier to work with. Otherwise, you're going to either get into some crazy bit manipulation and long switches, or end up just using if/else.

Comment: Well thanks for going out of your way to find a way of making switch work in this situation, but it looks like I'm stuck with 'if' statements for this one, combined with 'else' as suggested by @asc99c

Comment: @peachykeen: that's not one switch anymore. it also makes the code very obfuscated.