# Switch Statements and a MovieClips currentFrame

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a switch statement in as3 that keeps track of a MovieClips currentFrame and depending on which frame its reached changes a textFields content.

I think I have it pretty well sorted out using if and else statements but wanted to grasp my head around the case switch. Here is my code below that at the moment is doing the trick, although I'm hoping to get some better advice on it because I can't imagine this is a proper way of doing it.

```
animation.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, videoFrames);
function videoFrames(evt:Event):void{
trace (evt.target.currentFrame)

switch (evt.target.currentFrame){
    case 50:
            if(evt.target.currentFrame <= 50){
            content_txt.htmlText = content1Text;

            }
        break;

    case 51:
            if(evt.target.currentFrame >= 51){
            content_txt.htmlText = content2Text;

            }
        break;

    default: 
    //trace("");
    break;
}
```

}

So right now when animation is below 50 I get content1Text and once it goes over 50 I get content2Text and so on which is technically what I want. My question though is there a better way of doing this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Does this really work? I'd assume it will do nothing on all frames except 50 and 51. When going through your frames lineary, this will not make any difference. Your `if` statements are basically useless, as they are already covered by the `case`s. For ranges in `switch` statements, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5840887/2636001

Comment: @dst you're right, it only did anything when it hit 50 and 51. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of doing this that can eliminate the need for using `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, one of which involves a method called `addFrameScript` which runs a function when your `MovieClip` reaches a certain frame. **@dst** is correct in that your current implementation will not do anything until you reach frame 50 or 51. Also your if statements are not needed, they are saying the same thing as your switch/case. Here is one way you could do this using `addFrameScript`:

```
animation.addFrameScript( 50, toggleContentText );
animation.addFrameScript( 0, toggleContentText );
```

This addFrameScript takes frame 51, and the first frame of your animation and runs the toggleContentText function below:

```
function toggleContentText():void {
    content_txt.htmlText = content_txt.htmlText == content1Text ? content2Text : content1Text;
}
```

This function just checks which string the `content_text` is set to, and switches it accordingly ( it's the same as using an if/else statement ).